Understanding proof of Lah numbers exponential generating function
Lah numbers satisfy $L(n, k) = \frac{n!}{k!}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. In my Professor's lecture notes I found:

Lah numbers have the following exponential generating function:
$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} L(n, k) \frac{x^{n}}{n!} = \frac{1}{k!} \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{k}. $$
Proof. We can assume that $k \neq 0$. Applying explicit formula and binomial series, we get:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} L(n, k) \frac{x^{n}}{n!} &= \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{k!} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{x^{n}}{n!} \\
&=  \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \binom{n-1}{n-k} x^{n-k} \\
&=  \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k-1}{n} x^{n} \\
&=  \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-k}{n} (-x)^{n} \\
&= \frac{x^{k}}{k!} (1-x)^{-k}, \end{align} which is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{k!} \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{k}.$$

Now, the problem is that I don't understand what happens in the second step in further steps. I know that in the first step the explicit formula is used.
I need to study this proof for september's exam and I would really appreciate if someone could explain what is going on in this proof to me. Thank you!

There's a typo: $n!$ in the denominator has become $k!$.
The second step is then cancelling the $n!$'s, pulling out the term in front and writing the binomial coefficient by the symmetry formula $\binom{s}{t} = \binom{s}{s-t}$, for $s=n-1$ and $t=k-1$.
In the third step, I think there's another typo. Clearly the summation index is translated to start from $n=0$, but has been forgotten to change under the sigma.
Fourth step is using a formula for the generalization of binomial coefficient for negative number.
And then the (generalized) binomial formula in last step.
